# Should cheese be frozen?

Tags: cheese, food-preservation

I just put a piece of parmesan cheese into the freezer part of a fridge. Is this practice good or bad? I did this because when I bought the cheese, I could not back to home immediately and the cheese stayed in room temperature (30 degree celsius maybe) for a day, I was afraid that the cheese would be soften, so I made a though of putting it into the freezer. Then I did it and haven't taken it out yet. In addition, the package of the cheese is not yet opened.

Also I was afraid the lower part of the fridge would be open frequently and some air will condense within the fridge, so I thought put the cheese into the freezer maybe better, because the cheese was frozen.

Any comment?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I freeze cheese all the time, mostly mozzarella. It keeps longer. (If I keep mozzarella or similar cheeses too long in the fridge it gets moldy, often even before its expiration date.) However, I usually use frozen cheese only for cooking - i.e. if it's going to be melted. Freezing cheese does change the texture. Parmesan, though, being a hard, aged cheese would probably be less affected by freezing. However, on the same token, aged cheeses keep very nicely in the fridge, so I wouldn't see much benefit in freezing it.

Comment: Just thought I would add. Freezing something causes the water inside of it to expand and form ice crystals. When these ice crystals form they can rupture the internal structure of a food, in this case cheese. When a frozen food is thawed the ice crystals melt away, but the internal structure of the food is changed. Thus the change in texture.

Comment: This may be the affect of bursting ice crystals, but I actually prefer the softer texture of frozen -> defrosted cheese slices on my sandwiches. I do it with sliced muenster and havarti with impunity, and almost always prefer the texture.

Answer (score 3):

According to this website, freezing cheese is ok, as long as it isn't fine or aged cheese. But there will be a texture change with any cheese once it has been frozen.

http://www.thekitchn.com/thekitchn/the-cheesemonger/can-you-should-you-do-you-freeze-cheese-on-freezing-cheese-the-cheesemonger-117893

> Don't freeze fine cheese. Hand-crafted cheeses are delicate, and very
>   simply said, they'll deteriorate in the freezer. In a freezer, ice
>   crystals form within the paste of the cheese, and when cheese
>   defrosts, the molecular structure breaks down, transforming a
>   perfectly fine wedge into a mealy, more crumbly and dry version of its
>   former self. Cheeses with fissures, holes, or cracks are especially
>   susceptible to freezer damage.

On the subject of less delicate cheeses :

> The argument for freezing aged cheeses like parm and cheddar might
>   seem logical because they're more durable in the first place, and so
>   could withstand being frozen. But since most aged cheeses can
>   virtually last for ions in your refrigerator when stored properly, why
>   bother with the freezer, which can do more harm than good?

But they do offer this warning, there will be come texture change when these "industrial" cheeses are defrosted

> ...when defrosted, they'll be best used as melters, which will mask any
>   potential alteration to texture from their frozen stint. Bring on the
>   nachos!

Answer (score 1):

Cheese freezes well, although there is some textural change, especially with hard cheeses which tend to go crumbly. Fine for cooking - I freeze parmesan and gruyere.  Much better than leaving them in the fridge to slowly deteriorate. Never grate cheese and then store it - the flavour is lost very quickly!